# I want to login in Azure AD account in angular 8 application with one user detail stored in JSON file without redirect on Azure login page

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I want to login in Azure AD account in angular 8 application with one user detail stored in JSON file without redirect on Azure login page

I want to provide one system AD account to agents, so when agents open that URL system will get static azure AD account detail from constant json file and login it self without redirect to login page

Is it possible ?

Comment: Hi did you have a chance to look into my answer? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

No. If you want to sign in with the AAD account interactively, the redirection to the AAD identity provider is expected. In this case you can't bypass the redirection process.

See [The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) and [OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) for more details.

There is a workaround that allows you to log in in a "static" way: using [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc).

It requires you to submit the client id, client secret, username, password and the resource URI to the token endpoint. If the user has MFA enabled or is federated from on-premise AD it won't work.

```
POST {tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&scope=user.read%20openid%20profile%20offline_access
&username=MyUsername@myTenant.com
&password=SuperS3cret
&grant_type=password
```

Besides, please note the **Warning** tip:

> Microsoft recommends you do not use the ROPC flow. In most scenarios,
> more secure alternatives are available and recommended. This flow
> requires a very high degree of trust in the application, and carries
> risks which are not present in other flows. You should only use this
> flow when other more secure flows can't be used.